# Sets Having Special Properties

Tags: linear-algebra, set-theory

Let $\mathbb{F}^{n}_{2},$ where $n>3$ be the vector space of all $n$-tuples over binary field $\mathbb{F}_{2}=\{0, 1\}$ and $\mathrm{A}\subset \mathbb{F}^{n}_{2}$ be such that $\textbf{b}+\mathrm{A}\cap \mathrm{A}\neq \emptyset $ for all $\textbf{b}\in \mathbb{F}^{n}_{2} \ \text{and}\ \lvert\mathrm{A}\rvert=2^{n-1},$ where $\textbf{b}+\mathrm{A}=\{\textbf{b}+\textbf{a} : \textbf{a}\in \mathrm{A}\}.$  Then I want to prove $$\textbf{c}+\mathrm{A}\neq \mathrm{A}\ \text{for all}\ \textbf{c}\in \mathrm{A}\ \text{where}\ \textbf{c}\neq 0, \ \text{if}\ 0\in \mathrm{A}.$$ I have verified the result for n=4 in SageMath. Please help me in this regard for general $n$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jochen:  Yes, $\textbf{b}+\mathrm{A}\cap \mathrm{A}\neq \phi$ for all $\textbf{b}\in \mathbb{F}^{n}_{2},$ implies  $\textbf{c}+\mathrm{A}\cap \mathrm{A}\neq \phi$ for all $\textbf{c}\in \mathrm{A}.$ But this does not implies that $\textbf{c}+\mathrm{A}$ will be whole $\mathrm{A}$ for some $\textbf{c}\in \mathrm{A}.$

Comment: Does $A = \mathbb{F}_2^n$ break any of the assumptions?

Comment: Yes I think @SunilKumar should add the assumption that $A$ is not the whole of $\mathbb{F}_2^n$

Comment: @Chris Sanders: Yes, sir $\mathrm{A}\neq \mathbb{F}^{n}_{2}$

Comment: @Antoine: Yes, now I have corrected the statement.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work for $n=7$. Regard each vector as being made up of three pairs of digits plus a final digit.

Let $A'$ be the set containing every vector for which **none of the three pairs is $(1,1)$**.

Notice that $\dfrac{|A'|}{2^7}=\left(\dfrac{3}{4}\right)^3<\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Also, notice that $|A'|$ is even.

Finally, for all $b\in\mathbb{F}_2^7$, there exists $a_2,a_1\in A'$ such that $a_2-a_1=b$. (Exercise!)

Now, let us construct $A$ as a set containing every element of $A'$ but also adding in extra elements $\langle x,0\rangle$ and $\langle x,1\rangle$ where $x$ is supposed to represent the combination of three pairs. For each such $x$, if $A$ contains $\langle x,0\rangle$, I want $A$ to contain $\langle x,1\rangle$ as well.

Once you've added enough of these, you'll get exactly $\dfrac{|A|}{2^7}=\dfrac{1}{2}$, since $|A|$ is even.

But also, let $c$ be the vector with final digit $1$ and all other digits $0$. Observe that $c\in A$ and $c+A=A$. Also, since $A'\subset A$, for any $b\in\mathbb{F}_2^7$ you will still be able to find $a_2,a_1\in A$ such that $a_2-a_1=b$.

Comment: Yes I have checked the problem for $n=4$

Comment: @SunilKumar ah ok you've added another condition

Comment: @SunilKumar updated answer

Comment: I did not understand which $10$ extra elements have been added in $\mathrm{A}$ other than elements of ${\mathrm{A}}^{\prime}$ to make$\lvert \mathrm{A}\rvert=64.$  And  how we are ensured $\textbf{b}+\mathrm{A}\cap \mathrm{A}\neq \phi$ for all $\textbf{b}\in \mathbb{F}^{n}_{2}.$

Comment: $\textbf{b}+\mathrm{A}\cap \mathrm{A}\neq \phi$ is equivalent to saying that there exists $a_1,a_2\in A$ such that $a_2-a_1=b$. Furthermore, it doesn't really matter which extra elements you choose, as long as they are paired up in the way described @SunilKumar

Comment: Pretend you have the set $(0,0), (0,1), (1,0)$. Every element of $\mathbb{F}_2^2$ can be written as the difference of two elements of that set. This fact shows you how to prove that $\textbf{b}+\mathrm{A}\cap \mathrm{A}\neq \phi$

Comment: Sir could you provide me a concrete set with 64 elements. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: OK, let $A'$ contain every element $(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)$ such that the three conditions $(a,b)\neq(1,1)$ and $(c,d)\neq(1,1)$ and $(e,f)\neq(1,1)$ hold simultaneously. Add to this set every element $(a_0,b_0,c_0,d_0,e_0,f_0,g_0)$ such that $a_0=b_0=c_0=d_0=1$ is true. Further add $(1,1,1,0,0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1,0,0,0,1)$. Welcome to try @SunilKumar

Comment: Thank a lot sir.